# Redirection of traffic from one computer to another

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, forwarding, iptables-redirect

I have two computers on the same lan

```
Comp A: 192.1681.151.15
Comp B: 192.1681.151.19
```

When I open Wireshark, for all traffic browsed on comp A, I would like Wireshark to capture traffic of comp A and destination address as the one to the server it is connecting too.

I have tried to understand iptables and other related questions, but somehow I still configure this wrongly.

Edit:
I use the following iptable rules on comp B

```
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.151.19:443 
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.151.19:80 
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

How to correctly forward traffic from one computer to another ?. Both machines are connected to the Internet on the same lan.

Comment: How do you configure it then? Do you mind sharing?

Comment: Edit: Added the iptable rules that I used

Comment: But what is your exact problem? I mean: the iptables rules are not working, they work but you cannot see the traffic in wireshark, etc.

Comment: The iptable rules are not working for my setup. I cannot see traffic for wireshark running on the eth0 interface for computer B.

Comment: Is comp B your modem / router ? If it isn't, comp A traffic doesn't go through comp B, so you would need to set these rules on the router.